# Mysql columns limit. Using one table or create a new one?

Tags: php, mysql, json, normalization

I want to store trip details in mysql database. After storing these records, I want to perform some kind of searching and sorting operations on these records.
like:

```
....where from_city ='pune' OR from_pin ='411015' OR from_state ='MH' AND 
to_city ='pune' OR to_pin ='411015' OR to_state ='MH' AND Ddeparting_date ='2015-08-06'...
```

but I am confuse wether I have to store these record on only 1 table (**tbl_trip**) or if I have to make 1 extra table (**tbl_trip_extra_info**) so that I **can perform searching and sorting operation easily**.

I don't want to make my database too heavy.

**which is the best way for this situation** any body guide me ?

tbl_trip

```
trip_id  | from          | to    | pickup_points | departing_date  |..3 more
1        | address from1 | ****  | -------       | 2015-08-06      |..3 more
2        | address from2 | ***** | -----         | 2015-08-07      |..3 more
.
.
```

tbl_trip_extra_info

```
trip_id| from_city | from_state| from_pin| from_rout   | to_city   | to_state| to_pin  | to_rout
1      | pune      |MH         | 411015  | alandi road | pune      |MH       | 411015  | alandi road
2      | mumbai    |MH         | 412006  | patil road  | pune      |MH       | 411015  | alandi road
 .
 .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you should ask yourself is:

Is this a one-to-one relation or a one-to-many relation?

If you need one person and one trip so that you cannot have more than one trip for each person, the relation is one, so make one table and a column with the trip.

If you need the person to have more trips, of course is a one (person) to many (trips) so you should have one table for persons and one for trips.

At that point in the trip table you can search for the person id or similar.

If it's just a matter of trips and searching for trips, usually you would use only one table. You can search trips and once you have the search result you sort them the way you want.

**Addition**

Don't worry about column limit on a MySQL table, the limit is set to 4096 columns, so you should be fine. (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-count-limit.html))

Just make sure you set the correct indexes, so that the performance does not decrease.

Comment: i have only one-to-one relation i just worry about no of column. is join should be fast for filter or without join only increase extra column in same table